# Nginx Permission Denied but has permission (nginx, gunicorn, django)

Tags: python, django, nginx, raspberry-pi, http-status-code-403

I have tried to get rid of the error message for over 6 hours, but I can't still figure it out. 
 At First, I had my Django+React project directory at `/home/pi/pidjango` and I got a 403 Forbidden(css, js) Error message from Nginx, so I searched for a long time and I moved my project (`pidjango`) to `/home/pi/.local/share` and it seemed to be fine. Then I got a 502 Bad Gateway Error, and also fixed that (It was a problem from nginx) and I got 403 error again. It is the error about nginx not getting static files(css, js) and I gave `chmod 755` (-rwxr-xr-x) and it still doesn't work. Can anybody solve this? Thank you.

[I tried this tutorial(but except postgres)](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-debian-10)

```
$ sudo tail -F /var/log/nginx/error.log

*3 open() "/home/pi/.local/share/pidjango/static/css/main.js" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /static/frontend/main.js HTTP/1.1", host:"127.0.0.1", referrer: "http://127.0.0.1"
*3 open() "/home/pi/.local/share/pidjango/static/css/index.css" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /static/frontend/index.css HTTP/1.1", host:"127.0.0.1", referrer: "http://127.0.0.1"
*3 open() "/home/pi/.local/share/pidjango/static/css/main.js" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /static/frontend/main.js HTTP/1.1", host:"127.0.0.1", referrer: "http://127.0.0.1"
```

```
# nginx (sites-enabled)

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost 127.0.0.1;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/pi/.local/share/pidjango;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
}
```

```
gunicorn.service

[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=pi
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi/.local/share/pidjango
ExecStart=/home/pi/.local/share/pidango/djenv/bin/gunicorn \
         --access-logfile - \
         --workers 3 \
         --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock diary.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

```
gunicorn.socket

[Unit]
Description=gunicorn socket

[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/gunicorn.sock

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

```
Directory
/home/pi/.local/share/pidjango
   -diary (folder that contains wsgi.py, settings.py, etc)
   -djenv (virtual env)
   -frontend (react)
   -static (static folder)
   -db.sqlite3
   -manage.py
```

I have made sure I gave chmod 755 to all the static files in `/static`

Can anybody help?

*I have written all the scripts above by hand(not copy-pasting) so there could be typos

Comment: The first thing that sticks out is the folder. It is very uncommon to serve files from `~/.local/`.

Comment: I looked at a stackoverflow question and one of the answers are to move the project to either ~/.local/ or /var/www/ and I chose the first one. and it actually seemed to work.

Comment: Try changing your `User=pi` to `User=root`

Comment: Usually the `static` folder in your projects folder is sufficient.

Comment: @Lewis Do not run web applications as `root`!

Comment: @KlausD more to test permission not as hosting

Comment: Sorry, It doesn't work

Comment: and btw localhost and 127.0.0.1 seems to show a different error.
localhost shows 404 error
127.0.0.1 shows 403

Comment: @Lewis That is not what you wrote. Remember, many people come here, see something without context and apply that blindly! So always make sure that potential dangers are clearly stated!

Comment: hosting seems to follow localhost so i am willing that fixing this problem will also fix 404